# Check if file/folder is in a subdirectory in Ruby

Tags: ruby, file

What's the nicest way to check if a given file/directory is in some other directory (or one of its subdirectories)? Platform-independence and absolute/relative path handling would be nice.

One easy way is just to search through the files and check each time, but maybe there is a better one.

e.g. given directory `A`, is `A` anywhere in the directory subtree rooted at `B`, i.e. `is_underneath?(A,B)` or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correct.

An example:

```
require 'pathname'

A = '/usr/xxx/a/b/c.txt'
path = Pathname.new(A)

[
  '/usr/xxx/a/b',
  '/usr/yyy/a/b',
].each{|b|

  if path.fnmatch?(File.join(b,'**')) 
    puts "%s is in %s" % [A,b]
  else
    puts "%s is not in %s" % [A,b]
  end
}
```

Result:

```
/usr/xxx/a/b/c.txt is in /usr/xxx/a/b
/usr/xxx/a/b/c.txt is not in /usr/yyy/a/b
```

The solution uses the [class Pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html). An advantage of it: Pathname represents the name of a file or directory on the filesystem, but not the file itself. So you can make your test without a read access to the file.

The test itself is made with [`Pathname#fnmatch?`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-fnmatch) and a glob-pattern `File.join(path,'**')` (`**` means all sub-directories).

If you need it more often, you could extend `Pathname`:

```
require 'pathname'
class Pathname
  def is_underneath?(path)
    return self.fnmatch?(File.join(path,'**'))
  end
end

A = '/usr/xxx/a/b/c.txt'
path = Pathname.new(A)

[
  '/usr/xxx/a/b',
  '/usr/yyy/a/b',
].each{|b|
  if path.is_underneath?(b)
    puts "%s is in %s" % [A,b]
  else
    puts "%s is not in %s" % [A,b]
  end
}
```

To handle absolute/relative pathes it may help to expand the pathes like in (sorry, this is untested).

```
class Pathname
  def is_underneath?(path)
    return self.expand_path.fnmatch?(File.expand_path(File.join(path,'**')))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

A nice and quickly way is to use [`glob`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Dir.html#method-c-glob) method provided by `Dir` class in the Ruby stdlib.

```
glob( pattern, [flags] ) # => matches
```

> Expands pattern, which is an Array of patterns or a pattern String, and returns the results as matches or as arguments given to the block.

Works both with file and directory and allow you to search recursively.
It returns an array with the files/dirs which match the pattern, it will be empty if no one matches.

```
root = '/my_root'
value = 'et_voila.txt'

Dir.glob("#{root}/**/#{value}")

# ** Matches directories recursively.

# or you can pass also the relative path
Dir.glob("./foo/**/#{value}")
```